# Cannot run peer because error "Could not find config file. Please make sure that FABRIC_CFG_PATH is set to a path which contains core.yaml"

Tags: docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have create an application using hyperledger fabrics.

I got an error when create & join a channel.

```
"Fatal error when initializing core config : Could not find config file. Please make sure that FABRIC_CFG_PATH is set to a path which contains core.yaml"
```

This is my docker-compose-base.yaml:

```
   version: '2'

networks:
  dfarm:


services:

  # Orderer
  orderer.dfarmadmin.com:
    container_name: orderer.dfarmadmin.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CFG_PATH=/var/hyperledger/config
      # - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=DEBUG
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=orderer.dfarmadmin.com
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/genesis/dfarm-genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/msp
      - ORDERER_FILELEDGER_LOCATION=/var/ledger
    working_dir: $HOME
    command: orderer
    volumes:
    # Folder with genesis block
    - ${PWD}/config/orderer:/var/hyperledger/genesis
    # Map the folder with MSP for orderer
    - ${PWD}/client/orderer/orderer/msp:/var/hyperledger/msp
    # Map the current folder to cfg
    - ${PWD}/config/orderer:/var/hyperledger/config
    - ${HOME}/ledgers/ca/orderer.dfarmadmin.com:/var/ledger
    ports:
      - 7050:7050
    networks:
      - dfarm

  # Dfarmadmin peer1
  dfarmadmin-peer1.dfarmadmin.com:
    container_name: dfarmadmin-peer1.dfarmadmin.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CFG_PATH=/var/hyperledger/config
      # - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=debug
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG

      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock

      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_dfarm

      - CORE_PEER_ID=dfarmadmin-peer1.dfarmadmin.com
      # - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=dfarmretail-peer1.dfarmretail.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=dfarmadmin-peer1.dfarmadmin.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=dfarmadmin-peer1.dfarmadmin.com:7051
      # - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051
      # - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=0.0.0.0:7051

      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=DfarmadminMSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/var/hyperledger/msp
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=false
      # - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      # - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      # - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_FILESYSTEMPATH=/var/ledger
    working_dir: $HOME
    # command: peer node start --peer-chaincodedev=true
    command: peer node start

    volumes:
      # Folder with channel create tx file
      - ${PWD}/config:/var/hyperledger/channeltx
      # Map the folder with MSP for Peer
      - ${PWD}/client/dfarmadmin/peer1/msp:/var/hyperledger/msp
      # Map the current folder to cfg
      - ${PWD}/config:/var/hyperledger/config
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      # Ledger folder for the peer
      - ${HOME}/ledgers/ca/dfarmadmin-peer1.dfarmadmin.com/:/var/ledger
    depends_on: 
      - orderer.dfarmadmin.com
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7052:7052
      - 7053:7053
    networks:
      - dfarm

  # Dfarmretail peer1
  dfarmretail-peer1.dfarmretail.com:
    container_name: dfarmretail-peer1.dfarmretail.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CFG_PATH=/var/hyperledger/config
      # - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=debug
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=info

      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock

      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_dfarm

      - CORE_PEER_ID=dfarmretail-peer1.dfarmretail.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=dfarmretail-peer1.dfarmretail.com:8051
      # - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=dfarmretail-peer1.dfarmretail.com:8051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=dfarmretail-peer1.dfarmretail.com:8051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=dfarmretail-peer1.dfarmretail.com:8052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=dfarmretail-peer1.dfarmretail.com:8051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=DfarmretailMSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/var/hyperledger/msp
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=false
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb:5984
      # - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      # - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      # - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_FILESYSTEMPATH=/var/ledger
    working_dir: $HOME
    # command: peer node start --peer-chaincodedev=true
    command: peer node start

    volumes:
      # Folder with channel create tx file
      - ${PWD}/config:/var/hyperledger/channeltx
      # Map the folder with MSP for Peer
      - ${PWD}/client/dfarmretail/peer1/msp:/var/hyperledger/msp
      # Map the current folder to cfg
      - ${PWD}/config:/var/hyperledger/config
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      # Ledger folder for the peer
      - ${HOME}/ledgers/ca/dfarmretail-peer1.dfarmretail.com:/var/ledger
    depends_on: 
      - orderer.dfarmadmin.com
    ports:
      - 8051:8051
      - 8052:8052
      - 8053:8053
    networks:
      - dfarm

  couchdb:
    container_name: couchdb
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
    # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    ports:
      - 5984:5984
    networks:
      - dfarm


  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools
    tty: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=dfarmadmin-peer1.dfarmadmin.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=DfarmadminMSP
      #- CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
      -  CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/var/hyperledger/msp
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_KEEPALIVE=10
    working_dir:  $HOME
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/
        - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
    networks:
        - dfarm
    depends_on:
     - orderer.dfarmadmin.com
     - dfarmadmin-peer1.dfarmadmin.com
     - couchdb
```

My docker-compose-ca.yaml

```
# Docker compose for overriding the State DB setup for the peers
version: '2'

networks:
  dfarm:

services:
  root.caserver.com:
    container_name: root.caserver.com
    hostname: root
    domainname: caserver.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=root.caserver
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=false
      # - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
      # - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/CA1_PRIVATE_KEY
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --cfg.identities.allowremove --cfg.affiliations.allowremove' 
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/server:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server

    networks:
      - dfarm
```

My Init.sh file which is used for fabric-ca init

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-ca.yaml down
rm -rf ./server/*
rm -rf ./client/*
cp fabric-ca-server-config.yaml ./server
docker-compose -f docker-compose-ca.yaml up -d

sleep 3s

# Bootstrap enrollment
export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=$PWD/client/caserver/admin
fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://admin:adminpw@localhost:7054


######################
# Admin registration #
######################
echo "Registering: dfarmadmin-admin"
ATTRIBUTES='"hf.Registrar.Roles=peer,user,client","hf.AffiliationMgr=true","hf.Revoker=true","hf.Registrar.Attributes=*"'
fabric-ca-client register --id.type client --id.name dfarmadmin-admin --id.secret adminpw --id.affiliation dfarmadmin --id.attrs $ATTRIBUTES

# 3. Register dfarmretail-admin
echo "Registering: dfarmretail-admin"
ATTRIBUTES='"hf.Registrar.Roles=peer,user,client","hf.AffiliationMgr=true","hf.Revoker=true","hf.Registrar.Attributes=*"'
fabric-ca-client register --id.type client --id.name dfarmretail-admin --id.secret adminpw --id.affiliation dfarmretail --id.attrs $ATTRIBUTES

# 4. Register orderer-admin
echo "Registering: orderer-admin"
ATTRIBUTES='"hf.Registrar.Roles=orderer"'
fabric-ca-client register --id.type client --id.name orderer-admin --id.secret adminpw --id.affiliation orderer --id.attrs $ATTRIBUTES


####################
# Admin Enrollment #
####################
export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=$PWD/client/dfarmadmin/admin
fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://dfarmadmin-admin:adminpw@localhost:7054
mkdir -p $FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME/msp/admincerts
cp $FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME/../../caserver/admin/msp/signcerts/*  $FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME/msp/admincerts

export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=$PWD/client/dfarmretail/admin
fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://dfarmretail-admin:adminpw@localhost:7054
mkdir -p $FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME/msp/admincerts
cp $FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME/../../caserver/admin/msp/signcerts/*  $FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME/msp/admincerts

export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=$PWD/client/orderer/admin
fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://orderer-admin:adminpw@localhost:7054
mkdir -p $FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME/msp/admincerts
cp $FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME/../../caserver/admin/msp/signcerts/*  $FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME/msp/admincerts

#################
# Org MSP Setup #
#################
# Path to the CA certificate
ROOT_CA_CERTIFICATE=./server/ca-cert.pem
mkdir -p ./client/orderer/msp/admincerts
mkdir ./client/orderer/msp/cacerts
mkdir ./client/orderer/msp/keystore
cp $ROOT_CA_CERTIFICATE ./client/orderer/msp/cacerts
cp ./client/orderer/admin/msp/signcerts/* ./client/orderer/msp/admincerts   

mkdir -p ./client/dfarmadmin/msp/admincerts
mkdir ./client/dfarmadmin/msp/cacerts
mkdir ./client/dfarmadmin/msp/keystore
cp $ROOT_CA_CERTIFICATE ./client/dfarmadmin/msp/cacerts
cp ./client/dfarmadmin/admin/msp/signcerts/* ./client/dfarmadmin/msp/admincerts   

mkdir -p ./client/dfarmretail/msp/admincerts
mkdir ./client/dfarmretail/msp/cacerts
mkdir ./client/dfarmretail/msp/keystore
cp $ROOT_CA_CERTIFICATE ./client/dfarmretail/msp/cacerts
cp ./client/dfarmretail/admin/msp/signcerts/* ./client/dfarmretail/msp/admincerts   

######################
# Orderer Enrollment #
######################
export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=$PWD/client/orderer/admin
fabric-ca-client register --id.type orderer --id.name orderer --id.secret adminpw --id.affiliation orderer 
export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=$PWD/client/orderer/orderer
fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://orderer:adminpw@localhost:7054
cp -a $PWD/client/orderer/admin/msp/signcerts  $FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME/msp/admincerts

####################
# Peer Enrollments #
####################
export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=$PWD/client/dfarmadmin/admin
fabric-ca-client register --id.type peer --id.name dfarmadmin-peer1 --id.secret adminpw --id.affiliation dfarmadmin 
export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=$PWD/client/dfarmadmin/peer1
fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://dfarmadmin-peer1:adminpw@localhost:7054
cp -a $PWD/client/dfarmadmin/admin/msp/signcerts  $FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME/msp/admincerts

export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=$PWD/client/dfarmretail/admin
fabric-ca-client register --id.type peer --id.name dfarmretail-peer1 --id.secret adminpw --id.affiliation dfarmretail
export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=$PWD/client/dfarmretail/peer1
fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://dfarmretail-peer1:adminpw@localhost:7054
cp -a $PWD/client/dfarmretail/admin/msp/signcerts  $FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME/msp/admincerts


##############################
# User Enrollments Dfarmadmin only #
##############################
export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=$PWD/client/dfarmadmin/admin
ATTRIBUTES='"hf.AffiliationMgr=false:ecert","hf.Revoker=false:ecert","app.accounting.role=manager:ecert","department=accounting:ecert"'
fabric-ca-client register --id.type user --id.name mary --id.secret pw --id.affiliation dfarmadmin --id.attrs $ATTRIBUTES
export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=$PWD/client/dfarmadmin/mary
fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://mary:pw@localhost:7054
cp -a $PWD/client/dfarmadmin/admin/msp/signcerts  $FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME/msp/admincerts

export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=$PWD/client/dfarmadmin/admin
ATTRIBUTES='"hf.AffiliationMgr=false:ecert","hf.Revoker=false:ecert","app.accounting.role=accountant:ecert","department=accounting:ecert"'
fabric-ca-client register --id.type user --id.name john --id.secret pw --id.affiliation dfarmadmin --id.attrs $ATTRIBUTES
export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=$PWD/client/dfarmadmin/john
fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://john:pw@localhost:7054
cp -a $PWD/client/dfarmadmin/admin/msp/signcerts  $FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME/msp/admincerts

export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=$PWD/client/dfarmadmin/admin
ATTRIBUTES='"hf.AffiliationMgr=false:ecert","hf.Revoker=false:ecert","department=logistics:ecert","app.logistics.role=specialis:ecert"'
fabric-ca-client register --id.type user --id.name anil --id.secret pw --id.affiliation dfarmadmin --id.attrs $ATTRIBUTES
export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=$PWD/client/dfarmadmin/anil
fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://anil:pw@localhost:7054
cp -a $PWD/client/dfarmadmin/admin/msp/signcerts  $FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME/msp/admincerts

# Shutdown CA
# docker-compose -f docker-compose-ca.yaml down

# Setup network config
export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD/config
configtxgen -outputBlock  ./config/orderer/dfarm-genesis.block -channelID ordererchannel  -profile DfarmOrdererGenesis
configtxgen -outputCreateChannelTx  ./config/dfarmchannel.tx -channelID dfarmchannel  -profile DfarmChannel

ANCHOR_UPDATE_TX=./config/dfarm-anchor-update-dfarmadmin.tx
configtxgen -profile DfarmChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate $ANCHOR_UPDATE_TX -channelID dfarmchannel -asOrg DfarmadminMSP

ANCHOR_UPDATE_TX=./config/dfarm-anchor-update-dfarmretail.tx
configtxgen -profile DfarmChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate $ANCHOR_UPDATE_TX -channelID dfarmchannel -asOrg DfarmretailMSP
```

and last one setup.sh file used to initial the channel and join the peers to channel.

```
docker-compose down

# REMOVE the dev- container images also - TBD
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)            &> /dev/null
docker rmi $(docker images dev-* -q)    &> /dev/null
sudo rm -rf $HOME/ledgers/ca &> /dev/null

docker-compose up -d

SLEEP_TIME=3s
echo    '========= Submitting txn for channel creation as DfarmadminAdmin ============'
export CHANNEL_TX_FILE=./config/dfarm-channel.tx
export ORDERER_ADDRESS=orderer.dfarmadmin.com:7050
# export FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=DfarmadminMSP
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=$PWD/client/dfarmadmin/admin/msp
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=dfarmadmin-peer.dfarmadmin.com:7051
peer channel create -o $ORDERER_ADDRESS -c dfarmchannel -f ./dfarmchannel.tx

echo    '========= Joining the dfarmadmin-peer1 to Dfarm channel ============'
DFARM_CHANNEL_BLOCK=./dfarmchannel.block
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=dfarmadmin-peer.dfarmadmin.com:7051
peer channel join -o $ORDERER_ADDRESS -b $DFARM_CHANNEL_BLOCK
# Update anchor peer on channel for dfarmadmin
# sleep  3s
sleep $SLEEP_TIME
ANCHOR_UPDATE_TX=./config/dfarm-anchor-update-dfarmadmin.tx
peer channel update -o $ORDERER_ADDRESS -c dfarmchannel -f $ANCHOR_UPDATE_TX

echo    '========= Joining the dfarmretail-peer1 to Dfarm channel ============'
# peer channel fetch config $DFARM_CHANNEL_BLOCK -o $ORDERER_ADDRESS -c dfarmchannel
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=DfarmretailMSP
ORG_NAME=dfarmretail.com
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=dfarmretail-peer.dfarmretail.com:8051
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=$PWD/client/dfarmretail/admin/msp
peer channel join -o $ORDERER_ADDRESS -b $DFARM_CHANNEL_BLOCK
# Update anchor peer on channel for dfarmretail
sleep  $SLEEP_TIME
ANCHOR_UPDATE_TX=./config/dfarm-anchor-update-dfarmretail.tx
peer channel update -o $ORDERER_ADDRESS -c dfarmchannel -f $ANCHOR_UPDATE_TX
```

Please help me I tried lots but confused

for more detail folders and file   https://github.com/abhisamant7/Hyperledger_project/tree/master/network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FABRIC_CFG_PATH this variable requires the path of core.yaml. file

> ```
>   - FABRIC_CFG_PATH=/var/hyperledger/config
> ```

on /var/hyperledger/config you are trying to mount directory which does not exist so technically your path /var/hyperledger/config is empty

> ```
> - ${PWD}/config/orderer:/var/hyperledger/config
> ```

make this

> ```
> - ${PWD}/config:/var/hyperledger/config
> ```

this will work and just make sure all your mount are correct